# No signal lights after using hazards

Tags: electrical

I used my hazards on my 2004 grand am for aprox. Ten minutes ,now i have no signal lights ,fuses are all good and i swaped same relay out so thats not the problem ,at times i have. To jiggle the ignition key to turn key to start?

Comment: Try cycling the hazard switch a couple of times.

Comment: You write: "To jiggle the ignition key to turn key to start?" What is the relevance of this statement? What does it mean? Does the car also have a no-start problem?